# MathLink wrapper for NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, mathlink-or-wstp

I wonder if I can benefit from the Mathematica numerical quadrature routines in a way which integrates completely into an existing C-program. To be more specific I have C-program which does numerical quadrature using C-libraries like GSL (Gnu Scientific Library). These library functions are used by initializing data structures and running quadrature routines which take pointers to C-functions representing the the integrand and a pointer to a parameter structure which is fed to the integrand function as second parameter. Finally the data structures are freed. There is a set of functions for various kinds of integrands, but obviously there are some routines in Mathematica which are not implemented in the GSL. I wonder now if it is worth attempting to write wrapper functions for `NIntegrate` using MathLink such that I can use Mathematicas integration routines in just the same way as I would use C-library functions. Maybe there are MathLink examples out there which come close to what I want to achieve?

Comment: So what you need is this: call MathKernel from a C program in a way that MathKernel can call back to C to evaluate the function to be integrated.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, something like this. It needs to be efficient too, otherwise it will be useless.

Comment: I suspect that you are going to lose a lot on efficiency here.

Comment: That would be bad. Is there any other option apart from MathLink to use NIntegrate in a C-code? For instance, can the `Compile` function help me?